# BitArray to ByteArray not returning correct byte data

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I have a bit array that i am trying to convert to a byte array. But am having a difficult time working out the correct logic for it.

This is my bit array data:

```
1111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11101101
```

With an end result of:

```
[0]: 00011010 //this is obviously wrong should be: 11101101
[1]: 11111111 
[2]: 11111111 
[3]: 11111111 
[4]: 11111111 // also obviously wrong should be :00001111
```

This is clearly not right but just can't figure out the right logic at this point.

This is my method in my bitstream class:

```
    public void GetByteArray(byte[] buffer)
    {
        //1111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11101101
        int totalBytes = Mathf.CeilToInt(Pointer / 8f);
        int pointerPos = Pointer - 1; // read back should not change the current bitstream index

        for (int i = totalBytes-1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            int counter = 0; // next byte when == 8

            for (int j = pointerPos; j >= 0; --j)
            {
                counter++;
                pointerPos--;

                if (BitArray[j]) // if bit array [j] is true then `xor` 1
                    buffer[i] |= 1; 

                // we don't shift left for counter==8 to avoid adding extra 0
                if (counter < 8)
                    buffer[i] = (byte)(buffer[i] << 1);
                else
                    break; //next byte
            }
        }
    }
```

Can any one see where my logic is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use [`BitArray.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.copyto.aspx):

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
ba.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20247508

Comment: Ah damn thats embarrassing, wasted hours on this for it to be provided in one line. lol Thanks for that. Is there a way to see the source code of CopyTo i am curious how they did it so i can see where i went wrong.

Comment: Google is your friend :).

Comment: Here is how it is implemented in .NET Core: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/BitArray.cs#L509, and here is .NET Framework: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Collections/BitArray@cs/1/BitArray@cs